# Vectorized replace blank with NA over many objects

Tags: r, vectorization

I'm familiar with the below:

```
df[df == ''] <- NA
```

in order to assign NA values to blanks within a dataset. How can I vectorize this over a large number of df's? I've tried things like:

```
df_list <- list(df,df1,df2,...,df20)

1. lapply( df_list , function(x) { x[x == ''] <- NA } )

2. lapply( df_list , function(x) { replace( x , '' , NA ) } )

3. lapply( df_list, function(x) { assign(x[x == ''], NA) } )
```

etc.

Optional - An explanation for why the above wouldn't work would also be helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not returning anything from the annon function in the first example. For example, the below code works.
`lapply(df_list, function(x) { x[x == ''] <- NA; x } )`

Comment: Also `lapply(df_list, function(x) replace(x,x=="",NA) )` works, which is really just a wrapper around what you suggest.

Comment: OP's `replace()` example doesn't work because they don't pass a valid selection method to the second argument.

Comment: @thelatemail, I tried with the `assign`  but could really see how to use it for this.

Comment: I don't know if you can even use `assign` for this. I don't think it was intended for this sort of issue assigning to subsets.

Comment: `assign` is usually a bad idea anyway.